# JRebel Log file within the Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logging, jrebel

I just installed JRebel for Android Studio and I found it really useful but I can't get to show the logfile within the Android Studio IDE... Whenever I start the app inside my personal phone when hitting 'Jrebel Run', I just get the following log in the JRebel Log Screen. Is there a way I can print the logfile in the IDE?

```
#############################################################

 JRebel for Android 1.0.26 (2016-02-23T13:35:34+0000)
 (c) Copyright ZeroTurnaround AS, Estonia, Tartu.

#############################################################

Logs are kept in: /Users/jeremie/.jrebel-android/logs/com.plante.android.cobalt/debug

Service is already started in another process with PID 7285.
Stopping running service process.
Preparing application... This may take a minute.
Restarting application.
Application started and ready for use.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the JRebel for Android devs here.

The logs path is printed to the console for debugging reasons. There is no need for you to follow what is written to "~/.jrebel-android/logs/com.plante.android.cobalt/debug" as it is meant for us when something goes wrong with JRebel for Android and you submit a bug report from "Tools -> JRebel for Android -> Send feedback".

There is no way for you to follow the log files from Android Studio - all the important information will be printed to JRebel for Android console in the IDE.